# Bind server problem in centos8

Tags: centos, dns, bind

I have configured Bind server on Centos8 and I have updated the nameserver on my website yesterday. Now my site is down: When I ping to IP or ping website,  it wont reply.

Below is my configuration. Can someone please tell me where I'm wrong?

/etc/named.conf

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
    //listen-on port 53 { 172.31.46.1; };
    //listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory   "/var/named";
    dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
    recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
    allow-query     { localhost; 172.31.46.1; };

    /* 
     - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
     - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
       recursion. 
     - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
       control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
       cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
       attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
       reduce such attack surface 
    */
    recursion no;

        dnssec-enable yes; 
    dnssec-validation yes;

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";

    /* https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/CryptoPolicy */
    include "/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/bind.config";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";


zone "vimtrading.com" {
      type master;
      file "/var/named/named.vimtrading.com";
      allow-query { any; };
      allow-transfer { 87.101.216.99; };
};

      zone "1.158.137.3.in-addr.arpa" IN {
      type master;
      file "/var/named/named.vimtrading.com";
      allow-update { none; };
};
```

/vav/named/named.vimtrading.com

```
; zone file for vimtrading.com

; default TTL for this zone
$TTL 3H
@       IN SOA  ns1.vimtrading.com. hostmaster.vimtrading.com. (
                                2020111220  ; serial
                                        1D  ; refresh
                                        1H  ; retry
                                        1W  ; expire
                                        3H)     ; Negative cache TTL

; Name servers for this domain
        IN      NS      ns1.vimtrading.com.
        IN      NS      ns2.vimtrading.com.

; Mail server for this domain. A small number (0) implies higher priority.
        IN      MX     10      mail.vimtrading.com.
        IN      MX     10      mail2.vimtrading.com.

; A records
www     IN      A      3.137.158.1
@       IN      A      3.137.158.1
ns1     IN      A      3.137.158.1
ns2     IN      A      3.137.158.1
mail    IN      A      3.137.158.1
mail2   IN      A      3.137.158.1

; AAAA records 
mail    IN      AAAA   2001:16a2:cf3b:f00:7c0f:8033:c42:8da5

; CNAME records  
ftp     IN      CNAME  www.vimtrading.com

;TXT records (SPF, DKIM, DMARC, etc)
@               IN      TXT     "v=spf1 mx ~all"
dkim._domainkey IN      TXT     ("v=DKIM1; k=rsa; "
          "v=DKIM1;t=s;p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDiiweYt0xL3x2EuGUCpm8p35C10x7i25jHR66V7/PDSCVouLOrb8UlNkx/R5WQnflic9+TOR8+O+tR/xqnIqC/011cK/y+wiwa0n9/c5c1tqc8HJlCSy2Ym4h3KYflVc6AwBwdlrX6Sx4VdjQUsrcR8NWU6DoQOZsAdzZ+QbVYmwIDAQAB")

_dmarc          IN      TXT     "v=DMARC1; p=none; pct=100; rua=mailto:dmarc-reports@vimtrading.com.”
```

journalctl -eu named

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2021-03-13 09:59:01 UTC, end at Sun 2021-03-14 06:22:21 UTC. --
Mar 13 17:15:26 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 192.241.227.135#53473 (VERSION.BIND): query 'VERSION.BIND/TXT/CH' denied
Mar 13 21:41:43 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 157.245.89.85#59460 (googleadservices.com): query (cache) 'googleadservices.com/A/IN' denied
Mar 13 21:59:38 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 209.17.96.250#63361 (version.bind): query 'version.bind/TXT/CH' denied
Mar 13 22:41:26 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 18.236.135.177#44799 (ec2-18-236-135-177.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com): query (cache) 'ec2-18-236-135-177.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.co>
Mar 14 00:03:13 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 92.118.161.33#64674 (version.bind): query 'version.bind/TXT/CH' denied
Mar 14 00:35:22 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 162.142.125.157#59162 (213.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa): query (cache) '213.1.168.192.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN' denied
Mar 14 00:39:06 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 162.142.125.53#43631 (invalid.parrotdns.com): query (cache) 'invalid.parrotdns.com/A/IN' denied
Mar 14 02:04:19 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 74.82.47.30#43641 (dnsscan.shadowserver.org): query (cache) 'dnsscan.shadowserver.org/A/IN' denied
Mar 14 02:52:46 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 88.80.186.137#63454 (amazon.com): query (cache) 'amazon.com/A/IN' denied
Mar 14 02:52:47 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 88.80.186.137#63454 (1.158.137.3.in-addr.arpa): query '1.158.137.3.in-addr.arpa/PTR/IN' denied
Mar 14 02:52:47 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 88.80.186.137#63454 (3-137-158-1-604d6011.spiderprobe.com): query (cache) '3-137-158-1-604d6011.spiderprobe.com/A/IN' denied
Mar 14 03:02:08 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 185.94.111.1#56201 (com): query (cache) 'com/ANY/IN' denied
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com systemd[1]: Reloading Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: received control channel command 'reload'
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: loading configuration from '/etc/named.conf'
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: unable to open '/etc/bind.keys'; using built-in keys instead
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: looking for GeoIP2 databases in '/usr/share/GeoIP'
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: opened GeoIP2 database '/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb'
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: opened GeoIP2 database '/usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb'
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [32768, 60999]
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [32768, 60999]
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: sizing zone task pool based on 8 zones
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: none:104: 'max-cache-size 90%' - setting to 727MB (out of 807MB)
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: none:104: 'max-cache-size 90%' - setting to 727MB (out of 807MB)
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: configuring command channel from '/etc/rndc.key'
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: configuring command channel from '/etc/rndc.key'
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: reloading configuration succeeded
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: reloading zones succeeded
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:1::53#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:a8::e#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: all zones loaded
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: running
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:12::d0d#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:503:c27::2:30#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:200::b#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2f::f#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:9f::42#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:7fe::53#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2::c#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:2d::d#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:7fd::1#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:503:ba3e::2:30#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: network unreachable resolving './DNSKEY/IN': 2001:dc3::35#53
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com sh[14614]: server reload successful
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com systemd[1]: Reloaded Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Mar 14 03:28:01 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: managed-keys-zone: Key 20326 for zone . acceptance timer complete: key now trusted
Mar 14 04:16:22 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 209.17.97.114#53378 (VERSION.BIND): query 'VERSION.BIND/TXT/CH' denied
Mar 14 05:26:06 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 129.250.206.86#58289 (4ac0d748.openresolverproject.org): query (cache) '4ac0d748.openresolverproject.org/A/IN' denied
Mar 14 05:31:35 ns1.vimtrading.com named[6155]: client @0x7fbc400bfd20 192.35.168.75#39305 (c.afekv.com): query (cache) 'c.afekv.com/A/IN' denied
```

dig ajsaudi.com

```
rizwan@MacBook-Pro ~ % dig ajsaudi.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> ajsaudi.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 14367
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ajsaudi.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ajsaudi.com.        3600    IN  A   3.137.158.1

;; Query time: 144 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 14 09:36:48 +03 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

dig NS ajsaudi.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> NS ajsaudi.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30838
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:

;ajsaudi.com.           IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ajsaudi.com.        86400   IN  NS  ns1.vimtrading.com.
ajsaudi.com.        86400   IN  NS  ns2.vimtrading.com.

;; Query time: 89 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 14 10:32:19 +03 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 87
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. I am not sure if I understand you. First, does `dig` return the correct IP address? If so, I would say your DNS configuration is correct. I have the feeling that the problem has nothing to do with your DNS; after all, you can't access the web site with its IP address either.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When i dig it return the correct IP. But still i cant access the site IP as well.
Let me know if you want to see any other configuration or logs.

Comment: As I said, I can't see a connection between DNS and the web server. Perhaps you have configurations on the web server that reference the domain name? Is the web server able to resolve the name?